# OpenCV grabCut only outputs mask's values as background

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-segmentation

Where the **BLUE** color represents user's mask for foreground and the **GREEN** color represents user's mask for background, I get the below result. Actually only the mask's background marks are outputted as background:

[Screenshot http://s7.postimg.org/xwa8z5nez/maradona_problem.png]](http://s7.postimg.org/xwa8z5nez/maradona_problem.png])

The blue marks are saved in the mask as 0, while the green ones are saved as 1.

This is my code. Can you please help?

```
def run_grabcut():
    global output
    global mask
    bgdmodel = np.zeros((1, 65),np.float64)
    fgdmodel = np.zeros((1, 65),np.float64)
    cv2.grabCut(img, mask, None, bgdmodel, fgdmodel, 1, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
    mask2 = np.where((mask == 0), 255, 0).astype('uint8')
    cv2.bitwise_and(img ,img , output, mask = mask2)
```

Comment: Note that if I use 0 as BG and 1 as FG, and then `where((mask == 1)`, I get just the opposite - i.e. everything is black except for the pixels marked with 1, which look like in the original image

Comment: Can you provide a complete code and image which runs? Are you aware of that sample code? https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/grabcut.py

Comment: I finally solved it using a workaround, assuming that the algorithm does not perform well with mask, when no rectangle is passed first. So I save the (minX, maxX, minY, maxY) of the green marks and I create a rectangle of them. Then I first pass the rectangle to the algorithm to get the mask - and when I have the algoeithm's output mask for the rectangle, I append on it the green marks, and then I  use the algorithm on mask mode

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
mask2 = np.where((mask == 0), 255, 0).astype('uint8')
```

you are mapping all background pixels (mask ==0) to value 255 and all other types (e.g. foreground; mask ==1) to value 0

Adding

```
 mask3 = np.where((mask == 1), 127, 0).astype('uint8')
```

would create a separate mask for foreground. Is this what you are looking for?

Or do you want to also include the potential backgrounds (mask ==2)

```
 mask2 = np.where((mask==0) + (mask==2),255,0).astype('uint8')
```